# segmentation fault AND STRUCT

Tags: c

My goal is to store in the struct the items in the file. The file format 
looks like this:

XXXXX:TEMP>20:AC=OFF
YYYYY:TEMP<20:AC=ON   (etc)

All I am getting is segmentation fault (core dumped). I am guessing it is because of the struct. The code in the *while* I'm pretty sure it works, but I might be wrong.

```
char *rule=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*80);  
FILE *regra;
regra=fopen("SensorRules2.txt", "r+");


typedef struct r{

    char divisao[20];
    char sens[10];
    char op[2];
    int val;
    char atuadores[10];
    char estado[3];
}reg;



reg linha[42];
int l=0;

switch(atoi(MoteID)){
    case 1:

    while(fgets(rule, 80, regra)){

        strcpy(linha[l].divisao, strtok(rule, ":"));            
        aux=strtok(NULL, ":");
        strcpy(linha[l].sens, strtok(aux, ">"));
        strcpy(linha[l].op, ">");
        if(linha[l].sens == NULL){
         strcpy(linha[l].sens, strtok(aux, "<"));
         strcpy(linha[l].op, "<");
        }
        linha[l].val=atoi(strtok(NULL, ":"));
        strcpy(linha[l].atuadores, strtok(NULL, "="));
        strcpy(linha[l].estado, strtok(NULL, " "));

        l++;
    }
```

Comment: `strtok` is not reentrant. You can't process two strings at the same time.

Comment: you should use strncpy rather than strcpy to avoid overwriting the buffers allocated in the struct.

Comment: ... and you don't check for `NULL` pointer returned by `strtok` before it gets dereferenced by `strcpy`.

Comment: This code is not analyzable as-is due to the latent buffer overruns. Replace strcpy with strncpy for all of those copies into structs.